# skip execution after apply-template in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0, xslt-3.0

**Input xml:-**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Employees>
<data>
        <name>n2</name>
        <sal>1</sal>
</data>
</Employees>
```

**xslt:-**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/Employee/data">
    <xsl:variable name="name" select="./name"/>
        <Details>
            <EmployeeName>
              <xsl:choose>
                   <xsl:when test="not($name=('n1'))">
                   <xsl:apply-templates select="/Employee/data/name"/>
              </xsl:choose>
             </EmployeeName>
             <Salary>1000</Salary>   
        </Details>
    </xsl:template>
    
<xsl:template match="/Employee/data/name">
<FirstName>
 <xsl:value-of select="'CAT'"/>
</FirstName>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Expected output:-**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Details>
<EmployeeName>
        <FirstName>CAT</FirstName>
</EmployeeName>
</Details>
```

**current output is:-**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Details>
<EmployeeName>
        <FirstName>CAT</FirstName>
        <Salary>1000</Salary>
</EmployeeName>
</Details>
```

I don't want Salary tag should come in my response basically, how can i skip that based on some condition like if my flow came in apply-templates then it should not execute next code. can i do that in xslt ?

Comment: The stylesheet you have posted here produces an error, not the result you claim. It's also not clear what you're trying to achieve here. You have  2 templates that match the same thing (and  do not match anything in the given XML). Please put some more effort into it.

Answer (score 0):

Put it in predicate of a match, like this: ?

```
  <xsl:template match="/Employee/data[name='n1']"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="/Employee/data[not(name='n1')]">
    <Details>
      <EmployeeName>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="name"/>
      </EmployeeName>
    </Details>
  </xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think You use following code:-

```
    <Details>
        <EmployeeName>
          <xsl:choose>
               <xsl:when test="not($name=('n1'))">
               <xsl:apply-templates select="/Employee/data/name"/>
               </xsl:when>
               <xsl:otherwise>
         <Salary>1000</Salary>   
               </xsl:otherwise>
          </xsl:choose>
         </EmployeeName>
    </Details>
```

Comment: This is ok,i think i have not made it clear... my requirement is ,, if in case my sub template(/Employee/data/name)is called then do not comeback in main template to process anything. actually i am trying to do validation if validation fails then i am going in sub template and i have to return the response to consumer from sub template itself @Ajeet Singh